# How to use the input through get request as a variable in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am using fast API to do predictions. I am taking the if and the inputs through the get request and returning the response. But I want to change the endpoint dynamically from the input id given by the user and I was unable to do it. I am getting `name task_id is not defined`

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
class SoluteSolvent(BaseModel):
    solvent: str
    solute: str
    task_id: int

api_names = ['/predict','/predict_json']

@app.get(api_names[task_id])
def predict(task_id: int,solute: str, solvent: str):
    if task_id == 0:
        results = predictions(solute, solvent)
        response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
        response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
        return {'result': response}
    elif task_id == 1:
        return "this is second one"
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the endpoint dynamically? You could use RedirectResponse to redirect to `/predict_json` in the second case

Comment: You can't use `api_names` like that - these are configured when FastAPI starts up, not when a request comes in. If you want to have multiple endpoint names for the _same view function_, you can stack the `.get()` decorators (i.e. have multiple for the same underlying endpoint). However, I'd recommend moving the common code to a function then, and have two view endpoints that only contain the code that is actually different between them.